# API Feed Doesn't Give Me Data on Live Site

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

So i've got a problem with the YouTube API Feed.

On our live website it is not printing the feed's data, but when I go to our developer server everything prints correctly.

Here is a basic test page as an example: http://www.fleetistics.com/videos/test.php

I'm seeing nothing.

Here is a snippet of what I should be seeing:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => tag:youtube.com,2008:video:wzE9T5iy00Y
    [published] => 2013-03-25T19:13:32.000Z
    [updated] => 2013-06-05T13:29:37.000Z
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
                            [term] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat
                            [term] => Autos
                            [label] => Autos & Vehicles
                        )

                )

        )

    [title] => GPS Tracker Used by Action Lock and Safe
    [content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [type] => application/x-shockwave-flash
                    [src] => https://www.youtube.com/v/wzE9T5iy00Y?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata
                )

        )
```

Here is the code I'm using on the test.php page:

```
<?php
    $entryURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wzE9T5iy00Y?v=2';
    $feed = simplexml_load_file($entryURL);
?>

<pre><?php print_r($feed); ?></pre>
```

This basic example is using just the "videos" feed, but i'm having the same problem with all of the feeds.

Now these feeds were working correctly on Friday, so something happened between then and now.

I've ruled out that it might be a programming error because in the example I provided, I took out everything and left only the bare minimum. Plus the same code works great on the dev server.

I don't think it's the YouTube API because I'm not seeing any big announcements, and other feeds I see are working just fine.

So that leaves me to believe it is an issue with my website, or my account. I get the impression it is something with my account, since other feeds on my website using other applications are working ok.

How can I either fix this, or troubleshoot this further so I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds (and looks) suspiciously like the php flag `allow_url_fopen` has been shut off on your production server. If you have access to the php.ini file you can check that flag (it needs to be on to allow simplexml_load_file to load remote data). If it's a hosted environment where you don't have that access, you can check by writing a routine like this:

```
if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
   echo "it's on!";
} 
else {
   echo "it's off!";
}
```

If this is the problem, and you don't have permissions to turn it back on, you can use curl instead:

```
function curl_get_contents ($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$entryURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wzE9T5iy00Y?v=2';
$feed = simplexml_load_file(curl_get_contents($entryURL));
```

If this isn't the problem, check your logs to see if simplexml_load_file is throwing any errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I just tested your if statement, and allow_url_fopen is turned 'on' for our dev server, but 'off' for our live site. So this is looking promising. I'm going to contact my hosting service and see what I can get done before looking into curl. I'll keep you posted. Thanks again!